# how can be split string by dot and comma both

Tags: arrays, string, preg-split

I have a one string which is include ,(comma) and .(dot) .
I want to split both comma and dot . I am confused to split by dot and comma .

Comment: an example along with expected output would be better and also don't forget to show your attempts.

Comment: $string= "this is example of string , test . R.K.";    I want to explode value (test) and (R.K.) .

Comment: what's your expected output? could you show your attempts?

Comment: output  like as :   test R.K

Comment: Did you notice that `R.K`. also has dots ? if you explode, you'll get an array like this  `["test", "R", "K" ]`. I would go with a regex first and then loop the results.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a regex first and then loop the results, something like this:

```
$html = <<< LOB
this is example of string , test . R.K
this is second example of string , test2 . R.K2
LOB;

preg_match_all('/^.*?,(.*?)\.(.*?)$/im', $html, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {
    echo $matches[1][$i] . " " . $matches[2][$i];
}
//test R.K
//test2 R.K2
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://ideone.com/ZXBDW8)</kbd>

Comment: Hello there thanks . i have task can i share with you .

Comment: @aman Please mark this question as correct and open a new SO question, then post the link to the new question here and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: task is related this question

Comment: SO rules, not mine. Sorry about that.

Comment: To accept my answer as the correct one you need to click the tick (check mark) on left under the vote arrows.